# Relation and Equivalences: Finding the equivalence classes of a relation given

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Here is the problem:
Let R be the relation on N given by aRb if and only if 5 divides a-b.

a. Verify that R is an equivalence relation.

b. List the equivalence classes of R as sets. List at least 5 elements of each class; two of these elements should be negative.

I have already verified that R is an equivalence relation, but I am confused on where to start to list the equivalence classes of R as sets. Any explanation on how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: take the first 15 natural numbers, and by checking them against each other divide them into equivalence classes. It should then, hopefully, be clear how many equivalence classes  there are and how to identify them.

Comment: @MichaelCohen When you say this, you mean as in [1] = [5] correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence class of an element $r$ is given by
\begin{align*}
[r]&=\{x:5\text{ divides }(x-r)\}\\
&=\{x:x-r=5n\}\\
&=\{x:x=5n+r\}
\end{align*}
So, it is easy to see that $[r]$ is basically the set of all numbers $n$ such that $n\equiv r\pmod 5$. So, the equivalence classes are $[0]$, $[1]$, $[2]$, $[3]$, $[4]$.

Now, try listing the elements.

Comment: For [1], would the elements be what is found in [1]  mod 5? @SayanDutta

Comment: @roTenshi2 yes, check the edit